# linkedin api post showing image url

Tags: php, json, linkedin-api

This is the code ( PHP / JSON ) I'm using with Happyr LinkedIn PHP Class:

```
$linkedin_post = [
 'comment' => $social_msg,
 'visibility' => [
  'code' => 'anyone'
  ],
  'content' = [
   'title'       => '',
   'submitted-url'         => $social_img,
   'submitted-image-url'   => $social_img,
   'visibility' => [
    'code' => 'anyone'
   ]
  ];
 ];
```

The code works so that it posts the image and text but it shows the image url below the image so I need to stop the image url showing or somehow remove the image url link under the image.

Comment: Please explain that further - that specific code does only configure an array, it does not show anything at all

Comment: I don't think it's possible. I've tried it a lot in the past and the only section you can "hide" is the title. Also take a look at v2 for sharing images natively: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/share-on-linkedin#create-an-image-share